# Dynamic container name in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Alright, I have multiple buttons which call the same javascript function with a different ID.

Here's my function

```
function concur(id) {
    //alert(id);
    //throw ajax request
    $.ajax({ //create an ajax request to load_page.php
        type: "GET",
        url: "ajax_getter.php?requestid=1&r=" + id,
        dataType: "html", //expect html to be returned                
        success: function (response) {
            $("#container").html(response);
            //alert(response);
        }
    }); //ajax end
}
```

What would I do if I have to make the `id` as container name?
I mean, would this `$("#id").html(response);` work for all the dynamic changing ids within the function?
This didn't work for me. What would be the best solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use string concatenation to use a variable in the jQuery selector.

```
$("#" + id).html(response);
```

Comment: @AlexChar wasnt that the question?